# Keep SignalR connected in background in Android Oreo

Tags: signalr, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I used a service in my android app that check SignalR connection state every 10 seconds and if was disconnected, try to init SignalR and make it connected.

But in Android 8 some limitation added ([Read more](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services)), that kill background services and also we can't call `startService` method to start service from `BroadcastReceiver` that detect device boot completed.

What's your best solution to resolve this problem for all Android versions, that is better without any dependency?

Comment: For what do you need to check the state? Did you read about the KeepAlive packages? Do you cannot work with the disconnected event? Read more on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Comment: I check connection state to make sure SignalR is connected.
Actually My problem is when app/service was killed by Android, SignalR was killed, and not raise any event by SignalR to handle it.

Comment: I use EverNote JobManager (`https://github.com/evernote/android-job/`) to create scheduled job that check SignalR connection is in `connected` state or not

Comment: you cant do this, only white list app can run in background android, other were not accepted by doze